# Client-Side entity creation with related code tables

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous

I’m on the learning curve up the Silverlight trail.  I’m a data-centric developer so I naturally picked up the ADO.NET Data Services client along the way.  I’m scratching my head over a real-world scenario and can’t seem to find any help in documentation, blogs etc.

I’ve got a complex Tutor entity with related entity sets for Addresses, PhoneNumbers, and EmailAddresses.  I’ve also got a couple other sets like Subjects and Certifications.  Along with all this come foreign keys to lookup tables for things like StatusCodes, AddressTypes (like Home, Business etc), EmailTypes and so on.   All this is encapsulated in an edmx in my Model project.  Here’s a portion of the structure.

[image]

In Silverlight I’ve got a UserControl that is a data entry form for this tutor.  I’ve created a DTO like object for the data binding to the client’s TextBox controls.  All’s well till the user clicks Save.

The Save routine creates and adds a Tutor and Person objects and adds them to the DataServiceContext and links them properly.  Where I’m running into trouble is that I have to add a related entity that’s ALREADY stored in the context on the database such as code tables.

For example, the person may have multiple Subject specialties:  Elementary Math, Elementary Science etc.  The TutorSubjectSet has to relate to 3 other sets: Subject (e.g.. Math), SubjectLevel (e.g.. Elementary) and then to the Tutor.  My DTO has a list of combined Subject_With_Level items that presents a sub-set of a true Cartesian selection (there’s no such thing as Elementary (school) Calculus at least not where I went to school :-).  That list shows up as a checkbox list on the UI.  So, when the user clicks Save I pick up the checked items and I try to do a lookup on the combined Subject_With_Level.SubjectId and .SubjectLevelId values against the code tables that have those values.

This is where I’m lost.  In a server-side function, I’d be OK because I can do those lookups in-line and get the entity immediately.  In an Async situation, how do I get the related entities while I’m busy assembling the person graph?  Doing an Async call in the middle of the Save process doesn’t work.

I’ve tried various things:  I tried making an ad-hoc replica of the SubjectLevel using the Subject_With_Level.SubjectLevelId and attaching that to the context as follows:

```
public static SubjectLevel MakeFakeSubjectLevelFor(TutoringEntities ctx, Subject_With_Level subjectAndLevel)
{
     var subjectLevel = new SubjectLevel()
                       {
                         SubjectLevelId = subjectAndLevel.SubjectLevelId,
                         Description = subjectAndLevel.SubjectLevel,
                         EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now,
                         EnteredBy = "",
                         EnteredDate = DateTime.Now,
                         Type = subjectAndLevel.SubjectLevel
                       }; 
    try { ctx.AttachTo("SubjectLevelSet", subjectLevel); }
    catch { //this tries to catch situations where the level (eg. Elementary) has already been created }
    return subjectLevel; 
}
```

This approach works for situations where there are no duplicates (it also has the advantage that I don’t have to do an additional call.)  For example in Addresses, there will be only one Home address (I have a similar function: MakeAFakeAddressTypeFor()).  You’ll notice I have a try/catch that catches the error if the items is already inserted into the SubjectLevelSet. If the item has already been inserted and I hit that error, the returned subjectLevel is not attached to the context.  I get an error since the item is not being tracked.  However, I can’t retrieve an existing subjectLevel without issuing an Async query against the SubjectLevelSet even if it’s in my local context.

What I'd like to do is:

```
var lev = ctx.SubjectLevelSet.Where(l => l.SubjectLevelId == subjectAndLevel.SubjectLevelId).FirstOrDefault();
if(lev == null )
  lev = Helpers.MakeFakeSubjectLevelFor(ctx, subjectAndLevel);
```

but I get: "Specified method is not supported" which I assume means I have to do the query Async so I'm back to the same situation.

I’ve also tried to retrieve a list of SubjectLevels in the Loaded event delegate.  That way I’d have the set of SubjectElements on hand when the Save button is pushed.  Same problem, I have to issue an Async call to do a search even if I’ve got it in-hand.  I tried iterating through the list for the one I needed but that gave me an error saying that the entity was not being tracked by the context.

So… clearly I’m not understanding this and am doing it wrong but I can’t find any practical examples that do this kind of thing.  The how-to examples just happily load primitives into the entity to be stored.  No examples that I’ve seen show related entities and how to retrieve them.  I could make it simple and just store integer values for the codeId and not relate them via FK’s but that would be too much of a compromise.

Thanks for any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically speaking I think you feel that you have to do the query Async because it takes too long? Is that assumption correct? If that is the case, you should examine what you are trying to do with the query itself. I always find that if I can write the SQL to get exactly the data I want then I can move forward with writing the LINQ to it (using something like LINQPad).

Additionally, you can also make a SQL view which "flattens" your complex graph. Then in EF update wizard make sure you select the view. That way everytime you are building this custom complex DTO you can just issue a server side where clause instead and populate your values there.

If I am way out in left field just let me know, I have extensive experience with EF in very complex business data object scenarios and I am more than likely reading your situation incorrectly.

I think people on SO were not answering because it was lengthy and they were hoping for a bounty, just a guess though.